# Save token and user in session with vue and express

Tags: session, express, vue.js, token

I tried to make an authentication system. Everything goes ok but it is a small problem, the user is disconnected every time he refreshes the page. I think I have somehow saved the token and the user in a session but I do not know how.

Full project is here: [Github](https://github.com/gnome1337/coworking-lab/tree/Authentification)

```
// Token setup
function jwtSignUser(user) {
    const ONE_WEEK = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
    return jwt.sign(user, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: ONE_WEEK
  });
}
```

**How I send the data**

```
// Successfuly logged in
    if (response) {
      return res.send({
        user: existingUser.toJSON(),
        token: jwtSignUser(existingUser.toJSON())
      });
    }
```

Solution:
I solved this problem, you can find final project here
[Github](https://github.com/gnome1337/coworking-lab/tree/Authentification)

I changed method of saving token to localStorage

Comment: You can either store it in localStorage or cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem seems to be that you are storing the token in memory, and not localStorage

https://github.com/gnome1337/coworking-lab/blob/Authentification/client/src/store/store.js#L15

`state.token = token`

the store is not actually stored if you do a refresh, however the localStarage would be. There is a good writeup here: https://auth0.com/blog/build-an-app-with-vuejs/ that will help you achieve this. Read the article, or tl;dr; below...

```
// src/auth/index.js

import {router} from '../index'

// URL and endpoint constants
const API_URL = 'http://localhost:3001/'
const LOGIN_URL = API_URL + 'sessions/create/'
const SIGNUP_URL = API_URL + 'users/'

export default {

  // User object will let us check authentication status
  user: {
    authenticated: false
  },

  // Send a request to the login URL and save the returned JWT
  login(context, creds, redirect) {
    context.$http.post(LOGIN_URL, creds, (data) => {
      localStorage.setItem('id_token', data.id_token)
      localStorage.setItem('access_token', data.access_token)

      this.user.authenticated = true

      // Redirect to a specified route
      if(redirect) {
        router.go(redirect)        
      }

    }).error((err) => {
      context.error = err
    })
  },

  signup(context, creds, redirect) {
    context.$http.post(SIGNUP_URL, creds, (data) => {
      localStorage.setItem('id_token', data.id_token)
      localStorage.setItem('access_token', data.access_token)

      this.user.authenticated = true

      if(redirect) {
        router.go(redirect)        
      }

    }).error((err) => {
      context.error = err
    })
  },

  // To log out, we just need to remove the token
  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('id_token')
    localStorage.removeItem('access_token')
    this.user.authenticated = false
  },

  checkAuth() {
    var jwt = localStorage.getItem('id_token')
    if(jwt) {
      this.user.authenticated = true
    }
    else {
      this.user.authenticated = false      
    }
  },

  // The object to be passed as a header for authenticated requests
  getAuthHeader() {
    return {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I'll try. I can't rate your answer because reputation is low